# iphone alarm - ensure higher volume

Tags: iphone, ios

coming from Android i was surprised that iPhone alarm isn't smart enough to know that low volume will render alarm useless.

is there a way to ensure that the alarm will sound even if the phone has turned down volume and/or is on mute switch?

on android this was done via separate volume control in the alarm and "sound alarm even if phone is muted" setting.

if there is nothing equivalent perhaps there is some app that can do this?  otherwise they'll always be times where users forget to set appropriate volume before going to sleep.

Comment: The mute switch is ignored for alarms, but the system volume isn't, unfortunately.